# Connecting types defined in different modules in Fortran

Tags: oop, object, module, fortran, fortran95

I am writing a rather small pde-solving application in FORTRAN and I am trying to use OOP. Now, I have several modules, some of them define types with corresponding internal procedures.

Now the problem is what do I do if one module operates with a type defined within another module **and** the later model also operates with the type of the former? I give an example.

Say, I have two modules, one defines a type *Mesh*, the other one a type *NodeVariable*. Now I want each *NodeVariable* to be associated with the mesh it is going to be solved on, so I add a `type(Mesh) :: mesh` field in the type's definition. So far it is no problem I can write `use module-mesh` to get access to the definition of type *mesh*. But I also want the mesh to be aware of the variables defined on it  so I declare `type(NodeVariable), allocatable :: var(:)` as a field and add a procedure to add variables to the mesh on the fly. But now I am stuck, because I cannot afford another *use* statement: it causes the module to *use* itself and thus everything crashes. Solution?

Comment: You may need to create all your `TYPE()` definitions in one common module, and move the functions to separate secondary modules. This goes away from OOP, but we are still talking about Fortran here, remember. If you try to force too much OOP paradigm you will tie yourself in knots!

Comment: Submodules will be probably also handy in similar situations, but they are not widely supported yet, so I don't know them well enough.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'll have a special module just for the definitions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider your modules connected by use statements into a graph.  Fortran forbids cycles in this graph, as you have discovered.  The solution is to re-design your graph to avoid cycles.

In your case you could simply define both types in the same module.

Comment: Yeah, I guess this is the only answer possible. Thanks.